# Instead of all file I use "use strict" in node project. Can I use "use strict" at one place and that will apply in all files

Tags: node.js

Instead of all file I use 'use strict' in node project. Can I use 'use strict' at one place and that will apply in all files ?

Comment: Sorry It's my bad, I found the solution.

I added my start script and it works great

 "start": "node --use_strict ./bin/www"

and npm start for run project and works as expected

Comment: Yes Duplicate.. But Thanks @Mureinik

Comment: I also realize. Not to use it globally. Always use that in individual files else It will problematic in other's npm package because they not code in strict mode. So, I decide to use in my all project files.